# Variable not changing inside jquery click function

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

I have a list of most 17 recent entries from a db table and wanna use jquery/ajax to have a next button that loads the next 17 entries when you click it. 
It passes the 17 variable to the .load which works fine first time around (this is later used as mysql limit), but then I try to increase the start variable with 17 so that next time I click it would pass 34 to the .load (so it loads next 17 again) but this doesn't work, it simply loads same 17 again on 2nd, 3rd ect. click (so nothing changes). Reading other questions this should be the right way to use global variables by setting it with var and using it without var inside the function.

```
<script>  
var start = 17;  
var loadUrl = '<?php echo site_url('welcome/battles'); ?>';  
$("#latestbattlesnext").click(function () {  
    $('#left').load(loadUrl + "/" + start);  
    start = start + 17;  
});  
</script>
```

Comment: Is your `click` function reloading the page and resetting the `start` var?

Comment: Can we see the server-side script that returns the list?

Comment: Are you sure the "left" div doesn't include the "<script>" tag?

Comment: @alienwebguy console doesn't say anything at all at the second click, so I guess something messes up the code after first click.

Answer (score 0):

Is your site being refresh on any of these loads? Whatever is in the `<script>` tags is going to be refreshed as soon as the page it's loaded on is refreshed (obviously).

This is the right way to do it as far as I can tell.

Maybe double check this line:

```
$('#left').load(loadUrl + "/" + start);
```

To make sure it's not reloading any of the `<script>` on the page.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is right, aren't you setting the start var inside the .load function?

try changing the name of start inside the given script.

Answer (score 0):

Try this method:

```
var start = 17;  
var loadUrl = '<?php echo site_url('welcome/battles'); ?>';  
$("#latestbattlesnext").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: loadUrl + '/' + start,
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(data){
            $('#left').html(data);
            start = start + 17;
        },
        error(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            console.log(textStatus + ' -- ' + errorThrown);
        }
    });    
});
```

Comment: I get same result with that, but after adding the error thing I get this: [16:32:16.687] missing : after property id

Comment: Are you `json_encode()`ing your data or just `echo`ing html from the php page?

Comment: What do you see when you visit the url directly? `http://www.yoursite.com/welcome/battles/17` ?

Comment: I see the list with 2nd 17 entries and the button which is loaded at first click, also works with 34 ect. when going to the url directly

Comment: does that external page load scripts? It should be static html output - no javascript. Keep the JS on the parent.

Answer (score 0):

Increment the start variable either before the call to load or in the callback.

```
var start = 17;  
var loadUrl = '<?php echo site_url('welcome/battles'); ?>';  
$("#latestbattlesnext").click(function () {  
    start = start + 17;
    $('#left').load(loadUrl + "/" + start);  
});
```

Or

```
var start = 17;  
var loadUrl = '<?php echo site_url('welcome/battles'); ?>';  
$("#latestbattlesnext").click(function () {  
    $('#left').load(loadUrl + "/" + start, function() {
         start = start + 17;
    });
});
```

Comment: The second method worked for me. Does the callback succeed? Do you see the new html getting loaded? Are you maybe reinitializing the start variable? Please post any surrounding code in your original question. I suspect something else is the cause of your problem. Here's an example of the second method working. http://jsfiddle.net/craigm/hkSPZ/

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the load callback

```
var start = 17;  
var loadUrl = '<?php echo site_url('welcome/battles'); ?>';  
$("#latestbattlesnext").click(function () {  
   $('#left').load(loadUrl + "/" + start,function(){start = start + 17;});  
});
```